# CSS Grid system for form

Tags: html, css

I have a form that and I want the two `input` tags on top and the `textarea` on bottom. I have the following currently

```css
.uploadFile {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
}

.uploadForm {
    padding: 10px;
}

.uploadForm>button {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="uploadFile">
  <form action="includes/upload.inc.php" method="POST" class="uploadForm">
    <!-- <input type="file" name="file"> -->
     <input type="text" name="software-name" id="software-name">
     <input type="text" name="filename" placeholder="File name on DigitalOcean Space">
     <textarea name="software-description" id="software-desc" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
     <button type="submit">Upload</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

To better understand what I'm trying to do, here's a really bad illustration.

[image: illustration]

Comment: why dont you try with bootstrap?

Comment: I think of Boostrap as a prototyping framework and not good for real world stuff

Comment: Nope, it is used in real world stuff everywhere and all the time.

Comment: its not a prototyping framework. Its the most popular front-end mobile-first framework

Comment: I never said it waas a prototyping framework, I said I think of it as one. If it helps for you to understand, I don't want to use Bootstrap. I could care less if it's used all the time. I don't want to use it.

Comment: Took me a bit because I had to fight with Bootsrap's gutters, but for the heck of it, here it is in Bootstrap.  Only CSS is to remove the gutters.  https://www.bootply.com/hBkgAEN2Iz

Comment: Nevermind, Bootstrap has a class for no gutters too.  Zero CSS.  https://www.bootply.com/7Cirs9bkvY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a start. For the documentation have a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

```css
.uploadFile {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
}

.uploadForm {
    padding: 10px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50%);
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

.uploadForm>button {
    float: right;
    grid-column-start: 2;
}

textarea, input {
  width: 100%;
}

textarea {
  grid-column-start: span 2
}
```

```html
<div class="uploadFile">
  <form action="includes/upload.inc.php" method="POST" class="uploadForm">
    <!-- <input type="file" name="file"> -->
     <input type="text" name="software-name" id="software-name">
     <input type="text" name="filename" placeholder="File name on DigitalOcean Space">
     <textarea name="software-description" id="software-desc"></textarea>
     <button type="submit">Upload</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use css grid if that is an option as @SuperDJ demonstrated. This is an alternative solution using floats.

```css
* {
 box-sizing:border-box;
 }
.uploadFile {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
}

.uploadForm {
    padding: 10px;
}

.uploadForm>button {
    float: right;
    margin:10px 0 0 0;
}
#software-name,
#software-file {
  width:calc(50% - 5px);
  float:left;
  margin:0 0 10px 0;
}
#software-name {
  margin-right:5px;
}
#software-file {
  margin-left:5px;
}
#software-desc {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="uploadFile">
  <form action="includes/upload.inc.php" method="POST" class="uploadForm">
    <!-- <input type="file" name="file"> -->
     <input type="text" name="software-name" id="software-name">
     <input type="text" name="filename"  id="software-file" placeholder="File name on DigitalOcean Space">
     <textarea name="software-description" id="software-desc" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
     <button type="submit">Upload</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Now we just need a `display: table` answer and we'll have the 4 horsemen of the CSS apocalypse.

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon SuperDJ's answer, you can also use [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to achieve this formatting. To decide which one to use in your particular situation, you should read up on [the differences between the two](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Relationship_of_Grid_Layout) as they are similar, but still different.

---

**Edit:** This is just an example and may not work perfectly as is in all browsers. Make sure you implement any fallbacks and vendor prefixes that need to be implemented.

```css
/* New styles */

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.row-reverse {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.cell {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Pre-existing styles */

.uploadFile {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
}

.uploadForm {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="uploadFile">
  <form action="includes/upload.inc.php" method="POST" class="uploadForm">
    <!-- <input type="file" name="file"> -->
    <div class="row">
      <input type="text" name="software-name" id="software-name" class="cell">
      <input type="text" name="filename" placeholder="File name on DigitalOcean Space" class="cell">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <textarea name="software-description" id="software-desc" cols="30" rows="10" class="cell"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-reverse">
      <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Whoops, I see what you're talking about! Sorry about that, I'll adjust it.

Comment: Updated. It helps when the `input`s listen to me.

Comment: input is still going past the text area

Comment: Hm, I'm not getting that. It may be a browser issue. [Here's my view from Chrome.](https://i.imgur.com/zNkQuG7.png)

Comment: Must be, I'm in FF.

Answer (score 0):

Not using Bootstrap is a pain tbh, but here's how you can do it without it.

```css
.uploadFile {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
}

.uploadForm {
    padding: 10px;
}

.uploadForm>button {
    float: right;
}
.desc {
    width: 100%;
}
.form-group {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="uploadFile">
  <form action="includes/upload.inc.php" method="POST" class="uploadForm">
    <!-- <input type="file" name="file"> -->
     <div class="form-group">
       <input class="name" type="text" name="software-name" id="software-name">
       <input class="file" type="text" name="filename" placeholder="File name on DigitalOcean Space">
     </div>
     <textarea class="desc" name="software-description" id="software-desc" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
     <button class="submit" type="submit">Upload</button>
  </form>
</div>
```